Gauss map is a diffeomorphism
Consider a smooth, convex function $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$ such that the open subset $U=f^{-1}(-\infty, 0)$ has a smooth boundary $\partial U=f^{-1}(0)$. Consider the following smooth map $g: \partial U\to S^{n-1}$ given by $$x\mapsto \frac{df_x}{||df_x||}$$ Since the boundary is smooth the denominator is nonzero, i.e. $0$ is a regular value of $f$. Suppose $g$ is a diffeomorphism.

In this post someone proves that the map $g$ being a diffeomorphism means the curvature is everywhere positive. Is the converse true? What if I also add the condition $U$ is convex?
I would also like a sort of result, where one can say smooth maps like $f$ as described above, form a dense subset. That is, any map can be uniformly approximated by maps like above, on compact sets.
If we look at Lemma 2.3.2 of Notions of Convexity by Hormander, there it is stated that any compact convex subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ can be approximated to arbitrary precision by a compact convex subset of smooth boundary and positive curvature. Ideally, I would like to replace that with $\overline{U}$ where $U$ is as above.

An answer to any of the above questions or if you can point me toward references that would be very welcome. Thanks in advance.

Have you tried to answer these questions yourself? How far can you get with that? I don't know what your background is and how much math (specifically, basic analysis and differential geometry). Could you say?
